# how many minimum steps are required to rotate the dials (timeout)

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm solving this algorithm but got timeout.
Cloud you let me know I can I solve the question without timeout? Maybe my approach was wrong in the first place.

To be honest, it was my assignment and I already got failed. I just want to know what's wrong and review my code.

This is question.

[dial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drsrm.jpg)

The image above shows a lock with 5 dials. The number dials consist of a circular structure with the numbers 0 to 9 in sequence. When you turn the dial downwards, the number decreases, and when you turn it upwards, the number increases. For example, if the dial is pointing to 9 and you turn it one step down, it becomes 8; if you turn it one step up, it becomes 0.

However, this safe has a unique mechanism where turning one dial causes all the dials to the right of it to rotate together.

For example, let's say the current state of the dials is [1, 5, 9, 3, 7], and the set password is [2, 5 ,9 ,3 ,7]. If we turn the first dial one step up, all the dials move together and their numbers become [2 ,6 ,0 ,4 ,8]. If we then turn the second dial one step down, only dials from index 2 to index 5 move together and their numbers become [2 ,5 ,9 ,3 ,7]. By turning two dials in total, we have matched the password.

You want to know how many minimum steps are required to rotate the dials in order to match the password of this safe.

Given an array of integers called "dials" representing their initial states in sequential order and another array called "password" representing the password digits in sequential order for this safe as parameters. Complete a function called "solution" that returns an integer representing how many minimum steps are required to rotate the dials.

Constraints:

- 1 ≤ Length of dials = Length of password ≤ 100,000

  - 0 ≤ dials[i], password[i] ≤ 9
  - dials[i] represents the number that the i + 1-th dial initially points to.
  - password[i] represents the i + 1-th digit of the password.

This is my answer.

```py
def solution(dials, password):
    moves = 0
    for i in range(len(dials)):
        diff = min(abs(password[i] - dials[i]), 10 - abs(password[i] - dials[i]))
        moves += diff
        if i != len(dials) - 1:
            dials[i+1:] = [(d + (password[i] - dials[i])) % 10 for d in dials[i+1:]]
    return moves

# example
dials1 = [1, 5, 9, 3, 7]
password1 = [2, 5, 9 ,3 ,7]
print(solution(dials1,password1)) # Output:2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the differences, mod 10, between each dial and the previous dial. Assume a zero dial before the first one.

Every time you turn a dial, because all the dials after it move too, you change *exactly one difference*.  You just need to make the dial differences equal the password differences.

```python
def solution(dials, password):
    moves = 0
    prevdial = 0
    prevpw = 0
    for i in range(len(dials)):
        diffdiff = (dials[i] - prevdial) - (password[i] - prevpw)
        prevdial = dials[i]
        prevpw = password[i]
        moves += abs(((diffdiff + 25) % 10)-5)
    return moves
```